# repo sync stopped when download firefox code

Tags: git, firefox

When I download the code from Firefox, the repo sync stopped.

The following is the command I use:

git clone git://github.com/mozilla-b2g/B2G.git

cd B2G

./config.sh nexus-s

And it stopped at

```
Fetching projects:  87% (69/79)  Fetching project platform_external_opensans
Fetching projects:  88% (70/79)  Fetching project platform/external/openssl
Fetching projects:  89% (71/79)  Fetching project gaia.git
Fetching projects:  91% (72/79)  Fetching project platform/external/dbus
remote: Counting objects: 49, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 26 (delta 22), reused 26 (delta 22)
Unpacking objects: 100% (26/26), done.
From https://git.mozilla.org/releases/gaia
       8c9191d..d4760ba  master     -> mozillaorg/master
Fetching projects:  92% (73/79)  Fetching project platform/system/core
Fetching projects:  93% (74/79)  Fetching project platform/system/media
Fetching projects:  94% (75/79)  Fetching project platform/external/strace
Fetching projects: 100% (79/79), done.
```

I checked the net is ok, but, the system has stopped downloading files.

If anyone knows, please tell me, tks

Comment: Looking at the scripts that looks like that's all it should do. Try running build.sh?

Comment: when run build.sh display

Comment: when run build.sh display            root@skyworthserver3:/home/zhangxingcai/firefox/B2G# ./build.sh 
load-config.sh: line 7: /home/zhangxingcai/firefox/B2G/.config: No such file or directory
Could not load .config. Did you run config.sh?                              and at  the end of config.sh    it execute mv .tmp-config .config                  but in my system in stopped at repo sync,so it didn't executed

Comment: I'd send a bug to Mozilla if you haven't already

Comment: thank you i haven't got code yet